# WinForms WebView2 cpu load extremly high

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview, webview2

I've added the Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.**WebView2** control to my MainForm in my **WinForms project**. If its visible my **cpu loads extremly high**. The **difference** is like **30-50%**.

Do anybody have the **same issues?** Are their some **workarounds?**

**NuGet** is updated to the **latest version**.

**Already tried** this solution on github without any changes:

[**Github**](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/878)

Comment: Did you debug and see if any events are firing continuously?

Comment: yes, thants not the solution. I have read that the application must not be created for any cpu but only for x86 and then separately for x64. However, this did not solve the problem...

Comment: The advice for 'x86' and 'x64' no longer holds. They have fixed the bug, you can use 'AnyCpu' now.

Comment: We really need to see some code, your description is not enough.